# Cannot set cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I have a very simple line of code that set and read a cookie. I kept getting empty value for my cookie and have no understanding why. I have cookie enabled and know that cookies work on the browser.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            document.cookie = "ding=dong";
        </SCRIPT>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(document.cookie);
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: [Setting](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd8kd/) and [reading](http://jsfiddle.net/ttv2Q/1/) the cookie work fine for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I get blank alert from your link. I check under resource and there were no cookies. This is intriguing me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105135/cannot-set-cookies-in-javascript#comment73285208_12618175

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Recently I stumbled upon a similar issue. My script couldn't store a cookie in Chromium, although it worked well on all other major browsers. After some googling it turned out that Chrome ignores cookies from local pages. After I uploaded the page to remote server code magically started to work.

Comment: This right here is the answer; it'd be nice if OP would mark it as such.

Comment: Same on Google Chrome v38.

Comment: This is a whack answer. Thank you whoever ensured that this was the way things were.

Comment: Actually the answer is great, I just mean the actual logic behind the answer is trash.

Comment: As an alternative to cookies you can try using [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) which work even when accessed via file:///.

Comment: Unfortunately (confusingly) `window.localStorage` is blocked by Chrome's "block third-party cookies" setting for pages run from `file:///` but not from `http://`.

Comment: then how do local servers save cookies to browser for saving session

Comment: It would be a better answer if it told us how to store Cookies that worked locally.

Comment: In my case i was trying to store a cookie which exceeded the max browser size of 4096 bytes per cookie

Comment: Chrome will store cookies locally, but you have to be running a server and do it on something like http://localhost

Answer (score 8):

Chrome denies file cookies. To make your program work, you going to have to try it in a different browser or upload it to a remote server. Plus, the code for your setcookie and getcookie is essentially wrong. Try using this to set your cookie:

```
function setCookie(name,value,expires){
   document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ((expires==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + expires.toGMTString())
}
```

example of usage:

```
var expirydate=new Date();
expirydate.setTime( expirydate.getTime()+(100*60*60*24*100) )
setCookie('cookiename','cookiedata',expirydate)
// expirydate being a variable with the expiry date in it
// the one i have set for your convenience expires in 10 days
```

and this to get your cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
   var cookieName = name + "="
   var docCookie = document.cookie
   var cookieStart
   var end

   if (docCookie.length>0) {
      cookieStart = docCookie.indexOf(cookieName)
      if (cookieStart != -1) {
         cookieStart = cookieStart + cookieName.length
         end = docCookie.indexOf(";",cookieStart)
         if (end == -1) {
            end = docCookie.length
         }
         return unescape(docCookie.substring(cookieStart,end))
      }
   }
   return false
}
```

example of usage:

```
getCookie('cookiename');
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
CoolSmoothie

Answer (score 7):

I tried to save an cookie on Chrome and had the same error, that it would save.
Although it did work in Firefox, so I asked an collegue and he suggested that I take away path and domain (I had name of cookie, value, expire, path amd domain) and all of a sudden it worked.
So just to get the cookie to actually save in Chrome, you just need name, value and expire.

Hope it helps.

Example:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
     if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
     }
     else var expires = "";
     document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+";";
}
```

Comment: Developers should understand the implications of doing such a thing, unless they truly need a "just works" solution for some homework or related. There are other cookie values that may or may not require setting. Please visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie and understand cookies.

Comment: Perfect solution, This was the solution I was looking for so many days.

Comment: @John Castell : Thanks for the solution above, I too had the same problem and removing the path and domain worked for me, however I am still curious as to why this worked now and what hindrance do the path and domain parameter cause. I must admin I was facing the issue only in *http* protocols, *https* worked fine for me even with path and domain parameter.

Answer (score 3):

With chrome, *you cannot create cookies on a local website*, so you need to trick your browser into thinking this site is not local by doing the following:

1) Place the root directory of the web site into `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, (so it looks like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourProjectFolder`)

2) Get your `computer name` by right clicking `Computer`, clicking properties, and looking for `Computer Name`

3) Access your site in the browser by visiting `http://my-computer-name/yourProjectFolder/index.html`, at which point [creating cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) should work.

(**notice that I use dashes in the computer name, NOT underscores**)

Comment: I got the "<my-computer-name> refused to connect." error message.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same weird behavior when opening a page in Chrome from `localhost`

When I map the same page in my hosts file and open the same page through the mapped name, normal cookie functionality resumes.

1. Open you hosts file as admin. (usually `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)
2. Add `127.0.0.1    localhostdevelopment.com` or similar to the end of your hosts file
3. Save your hosts file (will be rejected if you did not open the file as admin)
4. Go  to http://localhostdevelopment.com/ (or whatever you called it) in Chrome.
5. Please enjoy having your cookies behave normally.

Comment: Remember that if we use this approach that the host name must end in a tld to actually trick chrome.

Comment: And, if you use `domain=xxx` on your cookie, be sure that your "local domain" matches that. (E.g. if you are developing something for example.com and hence set `domain=example.com`, then adding `local.example.com` to your hosts file should work.)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome doesn’t store cookies from the pages which are loaded from local file system. ex: file:///C:/User

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me but Once again Make sure if your `JS` and `Cookies` are enabled in browser. Your should check whether you cookie is setting properly or not using `if(document.cookie)`, it will then be easier for you debugging where the problem is. Maybe you're cookies are not written properly. Please do consider the following code.

**Write the Cookie**

Use the following code to write your cookie:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 cookie_name = "Basic_Cookie";
 function write_cookie() {
 if(document.cookie) {
 index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
 } else {
 index = -1;
 }

 if (index == -1) {
 document.cookie=cookie_name+"=1; expires=Wednesday, 01-Aug-2040 08:00:00 GMT";
 } else {
 countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
 countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
 if (countend == -1) {
 countend = document.cookie.length;
 }
 count = eval(document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend)) + 1;
 document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+count+"; expires=Wednesday, 01-Aug-2040 08:00:00 GMT";
 }
 }
 </script>
```

**Read Your Cookie**

Once you've written the cookie, you need to read it in order to use it. Use this script to read your cookie:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 function gettimes() {
 if(document.cookie) {
 index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
 if (index != -1) {
 countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
 countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
 if (countend == -1) {
 countend = document.cookie.length;
 }
 count = document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend);
 if (count == 1) {
 return (count+" time");
 } else {
 return (count+" times");
 }
 }
 }
 return ("0 times");
 }
 </script>
```

**Call Your Cookie in a Link**

Set your cookie when someone clicks a link with this code in your HTML body:

```
<script language="javascript">document.write(gettimes());</script>
```

Reference: [Simple Cookie Read & Write](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/a/aa083198.htm)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. Tried. and doesn't work. Blank. I know javascript and cookie is enabled and worked on my browser. So I have no idea what's going on. There's no where I can look to debug either..

Comment: change your browser..... Try it in IE or Chrome or FF. give it a go in any other browser. May be it will work. because it is working for me and there is no apparent issue in your code.

Comment: i tried FF, Chrome, and Safari (I develop on Mac). doesn't work. Is there anyway I can debug what's going on?

Comment: Set cookie expires time also, http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/web/jscookies.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) instead:-

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            localStorage.setItem("myCookie", "ding=dong");
        </SCRIPT>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(localStorage.getItem("myCookie"));
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the URL from the loopback network interface to the address of the NIC of your LAN will do the work, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080 -> http://192.168.1.15:8080
```