# unable to set cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I saw several questions asked to do this, and it seems like I am just following the same thing that is in the answer but I it seems like there is some error in my code.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        var curCookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "," + expires + ",path=/";
        document.cookie = curCookie
        alert("Your Cookie : " + document.cookie);
    }
```

I calling this function like this -

```
 setCookie("upperLimit", upperLimit, 10);
```

but alert only shows - Your Cookie :

Maybe there is some syntax error, but I am unable to figure it out.

Also, I have checked my settings for cookies and they seem to be as required.

Comment: What's the value of `upperLimit` when you call the function?

Comment: If `upperLimit` has a simple value, [your code as posted works fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/vvr31t7q/)

Comment: it is a number, say 30. It is not working on my machine. :(

Comment: Well, it is not working in chrome, it is working in ie. what can be the matter?

Comment: I have no idea. The **exact code you posted** works just fine in every browser I've tried. If there is *other* code, that is probably where the problem is. You might start by checking the browser console for  errors.

Comment: i think i got the answer here :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105135/cannot-set-cookies-in-javascript

Comment: You're probably right! That's a good little fact to know.