# Document.Cookie not showing in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using the setCookie() and getCookie() functions posted in an answer to this question

[Cannot set cookies in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105135/cannot-set-cookies-in-javascript)

When I set the cookie and reload the page, the cookie is there and working properly. But when I open a new tab (or close my current tab and reopen it) the cookie disappears. Is this because I'm developing locally or for some other reason?

Comment: @eykjs um, you can set cookies in JavaScript, not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: You should be setting an expiration date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie

Comment: Yea sorry that's just the title of the post I'm linking to, I know you can set cookies in Javascript. My problem is even with an expiration date I'm not getting the value back in a new tab. I'm using Chrome if that matters.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?I am having the same issue. When I open a new tab the cookie insnt there unless i reload the new tab. Due to this, i get an error page when opening the tab for the first time

Comment: I'm trying to jog my memory but I can't even remember which project I was working on for this. I'll keep digging through my repos to see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Might've been a CORS issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808537/cookies-headers-are-present-but-cookies-are-not-stored-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can create, read, and delete cookies with the document.cookie property.

With JavaScript, a cookie can be created like this:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
```

You can also add an expiry date (in UTC time). **By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed**:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

With a path parameter, you can tell the browser what path the cookie belongs to. By default, the cookie belongs to the current page.

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: So I thought it had to do with my expiry date not being set but I'm still getting the same result... Here's my code for clarification:

`function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    // same code as the setCookie method in the w3Schools link you sent
}

setCookie('accessToken', token, 1);
`

Can I not set a cookie when using localhost?