# Cookies headers are present but Cookies are not stored in browser

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, cookies

Please help me to figure out why the browser (Chrome and any others) does not set cookies, while Set-Cookie header is present in Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 345
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2020 21:15:53 GMT
ETag: W/"159-UXuykOchcveuYBb7xZpN5Luf3jU"
Set-Cookie: jwt=************; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 17 Apr 2020 21:15:53 GMT; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

My app running at: http://localhost:8080

Comment: How did you determine that the cookie was not set?

Comment: Application --> Cookies for localhost:8080 is empty

Comment: I'm still not sure where Application --> Cookies is?  And, I hope you know that cookies are stored by host only, no port.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the cookie.  Did you verify that it is not sent back to the host on a subsequent request?  You can just look in the Network tab of the Chrome debugger and see what's sent on another request to the same host.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome and in devtools you will find Application tab, in Storage section there are

Comment: I found the same question on github: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1553 but this did not help to solve my problem

Comment: Is the request coming from an axios call?  Because, if so, you have to set a particular option in your axios call so it will send cookies with the request.

Comment: FYI, I tried `res.set("Set-Cookie", "jwt=1234567890; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 17 Apr 2020 21:15:53 GMT; HttpOnly");` in an Express server here on localhost and the cookie was saved in the browser just fine and sent back to the server on the next request.  So, there must be something wrong with your specific code.  I think you will have to show us the relevant code, both client and server.  Also tried, `res.cookie("jwt", "987654321", {path: "/", httpOnly: true, expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000)})` and it worked too.

Comment: So, I can't reproduce your problem with my own code.  The issue must be in your specific code.  Can't really debug further without seeing that code.

Comment: I did almost the same: res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions), but browser does not store cookie

Comment: Well, works for me.  Not much further we can say without seeing your ACTUAL code.  Since there's nothing wrong with `res.cookie()`, it has to be something else with your code.

Comment: Here is server side: https://github.com/russian-stan/ms-backend/blob/master/controllers/authController.js

Comment: No, my server running on http://localhost:3000

Comment: I removed the Strict-Transport-Security header but it not helps

Comment: I think my problem is that I have client-side app on http://localhost:8080 and server-side app on http://localhost:3000. The browser store cookie if use ony http://localhost:3000. But what intetesting is that with Postman everyting is ok if use it for sending requests insted of localhost:8080, but not with localhost:8080 it doesn't work, it gets Set-Cookie header, but don't store cookie in browser

Comment: Did you solve it at the end @Stanislav? I am facing the same problem, my cookies are stored in the server's url not the client's one. I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: hey, @JavierGuzmán did you find the resolve the issue?

Comment: Hello @JuthiSarkerAka yes, if I recall well, do not use at all localhost, use 127.0.0.1 for everything

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You seem to be using CORS.

To set a cookie with CORS you'll need to set the `withCredentials` flag when making the request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

The server will need to return the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. You'll also need to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as you can't use wildcards on a request that uses credentials.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

As of Chrome 80 you'll also need to set `SameSite=None` and `Secure` directives on the cookie.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032
https://www.troyhunt.com/promiscuous-cookies-and-their-impending-death-via-the-samesite-policy/

To check whether a cookie is set you cannot simply open **Application > Cookies** to check for the cookie. The cookie will be set for `localhost:3000` so looking at the cookies for `localhost:8080` won't show it. Instead you'll need to open another tab that points to `localhost:3000` and then look at **Application > Cookies** in there. Cookies are shared between tabs so you'll still be able to see the cookies set by the original `localhost:8080` tab.

Getting cross-origin cookies to work with Safari is a separate struggle. If you need to support Safari I suggest you do some research into that as you may need to adopt a different strategy altogether.

Comment: why cookies will be set to port 3000? the Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be localhost:8080 then the cookie would be found in port 8080

Comment: @skirtle:  what would you recommend as a "different strategy" here for the cross-origin cookies?

Answer (score 3):

If anybode else has similar problem that you can see that the cookie is a part of the *response header* but you can't verify that the cookie is actually being set in the browser. It could be due to that the backend and frontend is on different domains. You are checking for the cookie in the frontend domain but it has been set with the backend servers domain. Go to the same url as the backend server and open your browsers storage and it will probably be there then.
**Chrome > f12 > application > storage > cookies**.

Comment: yeah my backend and frontend are on different domains, can you help me solve this issue...i have been struggling for 5 days now but no solution till now...Thanks in advance

Comment: @SairamGourishetty did you solved your issue? I have the same problem too.

Comment: yeah my issue is solved after using withCredentials: true in my axios config @0xTanvir

Answer (score 1):

If you using Axios just request with {{withCredentials:true}} statement
also in node js app.use(cors({credentials:true}))

Answer (score 1):

The probable solution could be **changing the *sameSite property to none***, if the frontend and backend part are in different hosting platform.

[image]