spring boot cookie not save and send by the browser
Hi have an spring boot application that in one service return a cookie with the following code:
public ResponseEntity<TokenDTO> login(@RequestBody CredentialsDTO credentials,HttpServletResponse response){
        TokenWithSessionDTO tokenDTO = authServiceFacade.login( credentials );
        if(credentials.getRememberMe() != null && credentials.getRememberMe() && tokenDTO.getSessionToken() != null) {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie( "gatestats-sessionId", tokenDTO.getSessionToken() );
            cookie.setMaxAge( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ); // expires in 7 days
            cookie.setPath( "/" );
            //cookie.setSecure( true );
            //cookie.setHttpOnly( true );
            response.addCookie( cookie );
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header( "withCredentials","true" ).body(tokenDTO.getToken());
    }

I also tried usisng ResponseCookie class instead
if(credentials.getRememberMe() != null && credentials.getRememberMe() && tokenDTO.getSessionToken() != null) {
            ResponseCookie cookie = SessionCookieGenerator.generateSessionCookie( tokenDTO.getSessionToken() );
            response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.toString());
        }

it does the same with the same result
I have commented just in case the httpOnly and the secure to see if this was the issue but it is not.
In the response in the browser I can perfectly see the header received


also is not shown in the application tab

also the cookies tab does not appear in the next requests
for example this one

I also tried just in case to see if it is received in the following request with the code of the authentication filter I have:
    if(request.getCookies() != null && idTokenWithBearer == null) {
      List<Cookie> persistentToken = List.of( request.getCookies() );
      Cookie seesionCookie = persistentToken.stream().filter( cookie -> cookie.getName().equals( "gatestats-sessionId" ) )
          .findAny().orElse( null );

But the getCookies method return null.
I am usisng as a front end an angular app and I have an interceptor with he "withCredentials: true", you can see other requests here:

here just in case you want to see all headers:

I also tried to change the cookie configuration with different domains as "localhost", "localhost:4200", "localhost:8080" and anything has work.
I am a bit new on cookies but as far as I know it should be shown in the application tab and then send automatically by the browser.
in postman it works nice


then withouth any Auth is sending the cookie automatically

The code I use in angular is the following in case you want to see it, but as I said the cookie does not even appear in the browser app tab.
so this is the interceptor that will send the withCredentials: true
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authServ : AuthService, private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return from(this.handle(request, next));
  }

  async handle(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const cookieExists:boolean=this.cookieService.check("gatestats-sessionId");

    const originalReq = request;
    if(cookieExists){
      request = originalReq.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'withCredentials': 'true'
        },
      });
      return next.handle(request).toPromise();
    }
    

    const token = this.authServ.getIdToken();

    if (token) {
      request = originalReq.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'withCredentials': 'true'
        },
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).toPromise();

  }
}


This is the http client request just for the login
login(email: string, password: string, rememberMe:boolean){
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'info',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      text: "Loging in"
    });
    Swal.showLoading();

    this.httpClient.post<TokenDTO>(`${environment.backendUrl}/auth/login`, new CredentialsDTO(email, password, rememberMe)).subscribe(
      (resp : TokenDTO) => {
        this.setIdToken(resp.idToken);
        this.setAccessToken(resp.accessToken);
        this.setTenant(resp.tenant);
        this.setWebcode(resp.webcode);
        this.setEmail(resp.email);
        this.setExpireAt(resp.expiresIn);
        Swal.close();
        this.router.navigate(['/blabla/home']);
      }
    );
  }

Take into account that the cookie is only sent back due to thereis a remeber me button that is received in the backend as shown in the spring boot code. The application works also with a JWT short live token used also with non remeber me is used.
Checking or not checking the remeberme it will received the normal access token, refresh tokens and so on, but if the user has check the remeber me then when going to the login page it will check if this cookie exists and it will use this token cookie directly
I also tried usisng http://127.0.0.1:4200/ instead of localhost just in case. Nothing works
the cors filter also is this one
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200",...more urls);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "*");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        res.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) { }
}

Thanks in advance for all your help and info.
Any additional information you want please add me a comment and I will update the question
UPDATE:
in angular I change this

And now I am getting a CORS error but not in the login request

maybe this can help

check the request headers of a ddbb call, in order to see if the cookie is being sent. Also withCredentials: true hast to be used in frontend code for credentials such as cookies to be sent

no, it is not sent, I will add an screenshot also if you want it. Also When I run the app in debug mode and I add a break in the "if(request.getCookies() != null" I can see there are null cookies for the rest of the responses. What you see in the top is the normal Authroization Bearer token that is used right now, not the cookie

yes I need to see 1. the angular code where you send the request in which you expect cookie to be sent with 2. (complete) request headers of the same request

u forgot to show request headers - and i mean in browser for the request that "doesn't work"

I will add them, but there is not only "one request" that doesnt work... once the cookie is in the browser it should be sent to ALL request automatically. As I said the request is not even shown in the application tab of the browser dev tool. Anyway I will add also the full screenshot of a sample request after "Supposing" to get the cookie. There you have the screenshot with all headers...the request works because also the client has the access token, but it should send the cookie same as in postman

I think I already have added all details but if still more details are needed don't hesitate to ask and I will add them, I am getting mad with this issue and still dont understand why the next request are not sending any cookie

I have looked over again and you are doing everything in the same or similar way as I have done it in my app where it works just fine. The problem is that browser rejects (doesn't set) your cookie, otherwise you would be able to see it in the application tab. So the only thing I can think of is that you have different domain for your server by any chance? Cause browser will reject a cookie that is send to a different domain from the server

alternatively could be cause CORS is not set, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808537/cookies-headers-are-present-but-cookies-are-not-stored-in-browser

Beware that withCredentials is not an HTTP header but an option when creating HTTP requests via XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials In Angular you can set it as the options in your HTTP request https://angular.dev/api/common/http/HttpClient#get:~:withCredentials (which under the hood will send this flag when creating the XMLHttpRequest)

Why does the cookie have a value sessionId=xxx  but your code shows gatestats-sessionId=... ?

because I was doing test changing also the name of this parameter. imagine all will be "gatestats-sessionId" if you prefer. it doest affect at all the behaviour of not sending the cookie automatically

is not the coors is not angular with withCredentails... I dont know what is happending but still is not working. I am getting mad

sorry was busy couple of days:) I just noticed in the cookie tab it shows your cookie as secure. That means the browser will only send it with secure (meaning https) connections. That means you need to explicitly set it as secure=false when you create it on the server with cookie.setSecure(secure);

Alternatively your problem could be because of CORS not being defined in your spring security config - here is a working configuration from my project:
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                              CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource
) throws Exception {
    return http
        .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource))
        .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            customizer -> customizer
                           .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/auth/login").permitAll()
                           .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
        .addFilterAfter(jwtTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
}


Hi thanks no problem mate, don't apologize for helping! Yes in the screenshot I added it as secure but then I remove it, I commented this part but forgot to change the screenshot sorry. I will edit the screenshots tomorrow

I have edited the screenshots already

Hi thanks for the edit, I have my cors configured but just in case I will show you my config also

I also added the coors filter
