# Is there any way to read a cookie created by JavaScript code in the Controller of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, cookies, asp.net-core

I want to ask that is there any way to read a cookie created by JavaScript code in the Controller?

**My application is in ASP.NET Core.**

In my View I am creating the cookie by JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
</script>
```

Now in my action method of the controller I try to read the  cookie but it did not find any cookie there:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var boh = Request.Cookies["username"];
    return View();
}
```

The value of boh comes out to be null saying no cookie.

I dug a bit deeper and inspected the "Network" area and found that cookie is not added to **Response**. See the below image:

[image]

If I can add the cookie to the response then I think it will be accessible in the controller, but how??

Is there any solution???

Thanks &  Regards

Comment: `var boh = Request.Cookies["username"].Value;` tried this?

Comment: @TanvirArjel there is no .Value property

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Is this cookie created before the request to the backend? How is the backend request handled? Is it on the same domain?

Comment: @Devon currently it's in local host. The cookie is created on View using javascript and i am trying to access it on the controller.

Comment: Is it the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618175/5928070

Comment: @TanvirArjel no this is not the problem. Cookie is set but not read in Controller in asp.net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that you need to encode the cookie value as pointed by out some expert. So I corrected it by doing the encoding:

```
$(function () {
  var cookieValue = encodeURIComponent("John Doe");
  document.cookie = "username=" + cookieValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking the cookies in `HttpContext.Request.Headers`, the cookie you set by `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";` is stored in `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]`.

Try code below to retrive the cookies.

```
StringValues values;
HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Cookie", out values);
var cookies = values.ToString().Split(';').ToList();
var result = cookies.Select(c => new { Key = c.Split('=')[0].Trim(), Value = c.Split('=')[1].Trim() }).ToList();
var username = result.Where(r => r.Key == "username").FirstOrDefault();
```